# How can I resize a vector to a specific size and resolution?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, apparel

I'm fairly new to design and I'm having issues resizing vectors.

My end goal : to print to a t shirt through something like redbubble/printful. They list a printable size of 7500px7500px

From my research, I think I need something like 300ppi?

How could I go about using an existing vector to scale it to those requirements in Adobe Illustrator?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's the great thing about vectors. You don't have to worry about "px" at all! But they do. So *do* contact them and ask how to handle vectors.

Comment: Why would you think pixel dimesnions and PPI at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

With Adobe Illustrator, creating vector content, there is no PPI to be concerned with. Vector graphic are *resolution independent* and don't adhere to any specific PPI.

So, you merely create a document with an artboard which is 7500x7500px and then create your artwork on that artboard.

---

If you are **placing raster images** into this Illustrator document, you will want to ensure all raster images are at 300ppi **before** you place them into the Illustrator document. And then **do NOT** enlarge placed raster images within Illustrator. Enlarging raster images within Illustrator will *lower the image PPI*.

If you intend to use the built-in effects withinin Illustrator such as drop shadows, blurs, and glows, you will want to adjust the **Document Raster Effects Settings** in the **Effects Menu**.

[image]

Set the `Resolution` drop down to "High" and the ppi field should then read "300".

[image]

Note that this **only alteres raster items created within Illustrator** this setting does **not** alter **any** placed raster images.

<sub>CS6 screenshots, but it's all the same in CC, windows may look slightly different that's all.</sub>